# Does Azure Data Factory supports regular expression matching?

Tags: regex, azure-data-factory

In my Azure Data Factory pipeline I have a filter activity where I need to check whether name of a file is matching a specific pattern.

eg: >the file should be a csv file and name should starts with 'D'.
>the name of the file must contain a specific word.

These values will come from a config file.

I want the implementation be something like this:
My config file will have an attribute called "filePatternt" which will be a regex.
In the filter activity, I will extract this attribute and will do something like ***regex.match(@myregular expression from file pattern attribute, @filename).***

But I am not finding any relevant article or regex function that I can use for the above.

Please let me know for any clue or solution or link you have.

Comment: what's the whole pipeline? Did you use look up +filter active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we copy data from blob to other, Data factory support using some expressions to filter the blobs in wildcard operations, like:

1. `*`: If you want to copy all blobs from a container or folder, additionally specify wildcardFileName as `*`.
2. `*.csv`: choose all the csv files from a container or folder.
3. `Start*`: copy all blobs from a container or folder which name start
   with 'Start'.

Ref:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#copy-activity-properties
2. [Folder and file filter examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#folder-and-file-filter-examples)

It may looks like the regex expression, but very simple.
[image]

Usually, Data Factory doesn't mention about regex expression, we will consider that it's not supported.

For you purpose "the file should be a csv file and name should starts with 'D'. >the name of the file must contain a specific word.", You could using bellow [Data Factory Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) in `Add dynamic content` help you achieve that:

```
startsWith()
contains()
endsWith()
and()
```

For example, I just create an example pipeline with Get Metadata and a If Condition. Using bellow condition expression to filter the csv file which name start with 'D' and contains a specific word:

1. Get metadata to get the file name.
2. If condition to filter the file.

I prefer to use If condition, the expression is same with Filter conditon:

```
@and(and(startswith(activity('Get Metadata3').output.itemName,'D'),contains(activity('Get Metadata3').output.itemName,'specifcWords')),endswith(activity('Get Metadata3').output.itemName,'.csv'))
```

[image]

If condition is true(the csv file which name start with 'D' and contains a specific word), we could add the case active.