# Azure Data Factory - How to put a wildcard for a filename including possible differences in lower or upper cases

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, wildcard

I'm trying to import files from my blob storage i.e; LowFix-*.csv is the wildcard of the file, however sometimes the files get sent to me where the lower and upper cases can change, and thus my automatic import doesn't trigger since the designated wildcard doesn't recognize the different in lower or upper case, it just looks at the designated name as I wrote it not any different variables with lower or upper case. How can I implement this in ADF?

I already tried making it Low???-*.csv, as mostly the lower and upper cases are changed in the 'fix' part, however I can't blindly rely on that so I need a different solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Azure Data Factory supports regular expression matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055604/does-azure-data-factory-supports-regular-expression-matching)

Answer (score 0):

ADF wild card paths won't support regular expressions and it won't ignore the case. It will only match the pattern that we gave.

To achieve your requirement, you can try the below workaround which involves the combination of Dataflow and copy activity.

First create a string parameter in the pipeline like below and give a filename to it.

[image]

Here, by using dataflow first we are going to generate a file consisting of required filtered file paths. Then give that file in the copy activity source **List of files**.

First give your source files dataset (give the file path till the folder)  to the dataflow source . In the source settings, create a column for `filepaths` like below.

[image]

It will give the result like below.

[image]

whatever might be the files schema, it will only take the schema of the first file and stores the file path of the rows in extra column.

Now, use **groupBy** on this `filepath` column using **Aggregate** transformation. In the `aggregate` section create a `count` column for any existing column for sample.

It will give the result like below.

[image]

Then use **Filter** transformation and filter out the file paths here using your pattern. Give your pattern in only one case and convert the `filepath` column also into that case like below.

```
instr(lower(filepath),'lowfix')>0
```

[image]

Then, remove the starting `/` in this column using **derivedColumn** transformation with below expression.

```
dropLeft(filepath,1)
```

Create a dataflow parameter of string type and use that in the Dataflow sink settings.

[image]

In the sink settings, use this parameter.

[image]

Go to **mapping** of this sink and remove the extra column `count` and kept only the `filepath` column.

This sink dataset should be a CSV dataset and uncheck the `First Row as header` in the dataset.

[image]

In the pipeline, pass the pipeline parameter to the dataflow and add the copy activity after it.

[image]

After the dataflow execution the **filepaths.csv** file will be generated like this with required file paths.

[image]

In the copy activity, use the same `filepaths_csv` dataset as source and select the above file path in the `List of files`.

[image]

Give your target dataset as sink to this copy activity. Execute the pipeline and the required files will be copied to the target like below.

[image]

**The Dataflow Code for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "sourcefiles",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "filepaths_csv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "aggregate1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "filter1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     filename as string",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          Id as string,",
                "          Name as string,",
                "          Age as string,",
                "          marks as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     rowUrlColumn: 'filepath',",
                "     wildcardPaths:['*']) ~> source1",
                "source1 aggregate(groupBy(filepath),",
                "     count = count(filepath)) ~> aggregate1",
                "aggregate1 filter(instr(lower(filepath),'lowfix')>0) ~> filter1",
                "filter1 derive(filepath = dropLeft(filepath,1)) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:[($filename)],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          filepath",
                "     ),",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will implement it tomorrow straight away and let you know, hero!